# what is the seeds.rb in db folder in Ruby on Rails ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

what is the relationship between db/seeds.rb and db/schema.rb? And How do I use them ?  by the way,

```
# db/seeds.rb

Todo.create!(title: 'grocery shopping', notes: 'pickles, eggs, red onion')
Todo.create!(title: 'wash the car')
Todo.create!(title: 'register kids for school', notes: 'Register Kira for Ruby Junior High and Caleb for Rails High School')
Todo.create!(title: 'check engine light', notes: 'The check engine light is on in the Tacoma')
Todo.create!(title: 'dog groomers', notes: 'Take Pinky and Redford to the groomers on Wednesday the 23rd')
```

I can't understand 'notes'

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789143/what-is-the-function-of-the-seeds-rb-file

Comment: Did you tried googling atleast before posting here ? A simple google search with seeds.rb - rails gives me the following - http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/seed_rb.html and http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **seed.rb** helps you to initialize data into your db.

You can run the file by:

```
rake db:seed
```

or run

```
rake db:setup
```

to create db, run migrations, and run seed

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you create a db and you can fill it with seeds.rb. In other words, you fill your tables in accordance with the model you generated beforehand.

```
User.create (username: "tony", password: "12345666")
User.create (username: "Clara", password: "fdvfdvfd666")
User.create (username: "Hans", password: "1gbfdbg2345666")
```